# C# Listbox sort items

Tags: c#, file, listbox

Im new to programming and Im having a problem with a listbox. Im reading text from a file, and I want the last file in the file to be the first in the listbox. How to I do this??
This is a school project :)

This is the code I have so far:

```
if (File.Exists(file))
        {

            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo("nema.csv");
            StreamReader read = fileInfo.OpenText();
            while (!read.EndOfStream)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(read.ReadLine());
            }

            read.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Show the code you have so far.

Comment: Could you put in what you're currently doing so i'll have a starting point to helping you out ?

Comment: It would also help to know, what kind of UI framework you are using. WPF? WinForms?

Answer (score 4):

it's hard to tell without code but basically you have to use `Insert(0,item)` instead of `Add(item)` to reverse the order. The code coud look something like this:

```
using(var reader = System.IO.File.OpenText(pathOfFile))
{
   myListBox.Items.Insert(0, reader.ReadLine());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Read the contents of the file.
- Put them in a list
- Add the items that
  are in the list to the ListBox, but make sure you start from the last
  item in the list, and go to the first.

Answer (score 0):

To add a new object at the first place of the listbox
listbox.Items.Insert(0, objectToAdd)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you to handle read textfile

While Reading TextFile store all string in a List Collection.

```
        List<string> listItems = new List<string>();
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\YourFile.txt", FileMode.Open);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);

        string line = "";

        int lineNo = 0;
        do {
            line = sr.ReadLine();
            if (line != null) {
                listItems.Add(line);
            }
        } while (line != null);
        listItems.Sort();

        foreach(string s in listItems)
        {
              yourListBox.Items.Add(s);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use Listview either than listbox.

1. Go to properties of ListView
2. Click the SORTING
3. Choose descending